# Cat + Tag Filter Plugin for WordPress: Checkboxes not being saved

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, foreach

I'm using the Cat + Tag Filter Plugin for WordPress and it works fine except that the checkboxes that are supposed to be saved between tag searches are not being saved. All but the last one selected is being cleared, leading me to suspect that there is something wrong in the foreach statement that displays each checkbox and checks to see if that tag was included in the tag array.

My question is, how can I keep the tag checkboxes checked and not just the last one and is there anything wrong with this foreach statement?

```
if ($type == 1){
    if ($there_are_tags){
    $options .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $options .= '<li>'; 
        $options .= '<input type="checkbox" name="';
        $options .= "tag[]";
        $options .= '" value="' . $tag->slug . '"';
        if (is_array($current_tax['tags'])) {
            if (in_array($tag->slug, $current_tax['tags'])) { 
                $options .= ' checked '; 
            }
        }
        $options .= '>';
        $options .= $tag->name;
        if ($ctf_options['tags_count'] == 1) $options .= ' (' . $tag->count . ')';
        $options .= '</li>';    
    }
    $options .= '</ul>';
    }
    else $options .= '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="-1" disabled>' .  __('No tags here', 'cat-tag-filter')  . '</li></ul>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is a well documented list of issues with this plugin and not a very good response rate from the plugins creators. Some posts recent about the plugin are saying that it doesn't work at all with Wordpress 3.6. Your options are some what limited, you can put a bounty on the issues and try and attract some to do a custom fix on the issues for the plugin, you can hold out for a plugin update or you can try implementing something like Isoptope for Wordpress (this has a bit learning curve to use).

Lastly, I just found that if you have the Yoast or Pretty Permalinks plugins installed there are documented conflicts with these plug-ins and Cat+Tags filter so you could try turn some of your plugins on and off to see if this fixes the issue for you.

I hope this helps some.